# I can not do a swap operation while sorting. It crashes when I do it. Why?

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct

```
struct Dates
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
}accountinfo[3];

struct Accounts
{
    string name,lastname;
    int number;
    float balance;
}account[3];

void sortduetoaccnumbers()
{
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            if (account[j].number>account[j+1].number)
            {
                //swap
            }
        }
    }
}
void sortduetodates()
{
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            if (accountinfo[j].year>accountinfo[j+1].year)
            {
                //swap
            }
            else if (accountinfo[j].year==accountinfo[j+1].year)
            {
                if (accountinfo[j].month>accountinfo[j+1].month)
                {
                    //swap
                }
                else if (accountinfo[j].month==accountinfo[j+1].month)
                {
                    if (accountinfo[j].day>accountinfo[j+1].day)
                    {
                        //swap
                    }
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

I can not sort these accounts using sorting algorithms. It crashes if I enter them. cmd stops suddenly and finishes the program.

I entered a comment line where swapping functions have to go. So you can analyze the code.

Every other functions are working except this one. I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: Your questions will generally get a much better reception if you include a [mcve].

Comment: It appears that `i` and `j` may be global variables. You may find this to be an awesomely bad idea. You should always give variables the smallest possible scope to prevent confusion and unintended simultaneous use. For example, `or (i=0;i<3;i++)` would be much safer as `or (int i=0;i<3;i++)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this code is wrong:
`if (accountinfo[j].year>accountinfo[j+1].year)`
because if j==2, then j+1=3 - index over array size => undefined behavior (and crash in your case)

you need to change loop condition to `j<2` or rewrite your checks

Comment: Worth noting, the same mistake is repeated throughout the posted source.

Comment: yes, I wrote one line as visual example of same mistakes